# OBSOLETE - Swatch: A Firefox plugin for monitoring Stack Exchange sites for interesting changes

Tags: app, obsolete, notifications, firefox

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

### About

A Firefox extension that lets you monitor your account activity on any Stack Exchange site that support the Stack Apps API. Automatically refreshes on a set interval to display your latest stats.

Now has a handy toolbar that monitors mention changes and where you can see the latest mentions.

Support for monitoring questions/answers will be added in the future.

Instructions for using the plugin can be found [here](http://www.ioncannon.net/projects/swatch/).

#### Change Log

The following is a short list of main features added with each release.

**Version 1.6**

- Support for version 1.0 of the API

**Version 1.3**

- Now forcing all refresh frequency to be greater than 60 seconds

**Version 1.2**

- Added toolbar button and icon, will update with status changes
- Added support for monitoring mentions
- Added highlights to changed values so you can tell what changed
- Added ability to change format of reputation display from short to full (see the add-on preferences for that option)

**Version 1.0**

- Initial release

#### License

MIT

#### Download

You can find the addon on the Firefox [plugin page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/162033/).

#### Platform

Firefox 3+ on all platforms.

### Contact

I have set up a Google group for [Swatch support](http://groups.google.com/group/swatch-support). I can also be reached by email swatch@ioncannon.net.

### Source

The [Swatch source](http://github.com/carsonmcdonald/Swatch) can be found on github.

Comment: +1 Pretty cool work.I've already two feature requests: 1. A ding sound when reputations change. 2. A third stat with reputation and badges together.

Comment: Is it possible to show the rep without the "k" notation?

Comment: @systempuntoout I'll add an optional ding if I can. 
@espo I'll make it an option.

Comment: I have a small problem. When I tell Swatch to find my user name it returns an error "There was a problem with the request: Status code = 500" Any ideas?

Comment: @Pulse are you getting that when you try to find your id on stack overflow or one of the other sites? Can you tell me exactly what you typed into the search field?

Comment: Hi. Select 'configure' from the status bar, select a site that I am logged into, such as Super User or Server Fault, select  'search', enter my user name and select 'Lookup' The extension says it's searching but after approximately 20 seconds it returns the error message noted above. All sites respond the same way.

Comment: @Pulse I think I need to know exactly what you are entering as your name. My guess is that something isn't being encoded correctly and I need to fix that. Can you give me an example of what user name you are entering that gives you that error? Can you try searching for something like "Jon" and tell me if that breaks as well?

Comment: I am using Pulse for the user name although I did try my real name, just in case. I also tried your name (carson)for the Stack Apps site and one or two other names, chosen at random from the other Stack sites. They all return the same error.

Comment: @Pulse Can you tell me the version of firefox you are using? This could be a tough one to track down. It may also help if we move the conversation over to the support group that I set up here http://groups.google.com/group/swatch-support

Comment: I'm running 3.6.6pre but I can download a 3.6.3/4 version and see if it makes a difference, it will only take a few minutes. I'll move over to the google group now.

Comment: You didn't do this, did you? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/54597/can-anyone-explain-why-im-getting-in-crap-from-i-t-because-of-bandwidth-to-api

Comment: @George Stocker The plugin polls so I could see that happening. Depending on how many profiles the person configures, how many mentions they have and how quickly they tell it to poll. A 15 second poll would work out to 10.5KB each poll and that is still pretty big, all my info polls in about 2KB.

Comment: @Carson "you can change the polling frequency in the preferences to poll less".. where can i find this preferences? I just see the Stack Exchange Uid on Swatch options.

Comment: @systempuntoout Go to Tools->Add-ons then select the extension then the "Preferences" button on the extension.

Comment: @Carson found it. Uhm, imho you should integrate userid and frequence configurations in one single panel reachable from Swatch option entry on tools menu or from preferences on Add-ons. That's how many ff extensions work out there (mine too :) ).

Comment: @Carson are you still developing it?

Comment: I haven't had time to do much to it lately but I'll eventually get back around to it. I have lost some interest in the API due to what seems to be very little user interest in the tools created with it. I use the plugin though so I know I want to fix some of the missing parts soon so I can track a couple new sites.

Comment: @carson the hard-coded favicon are gone :(

Comment: I thought I could use it with other stack exchange sites like *programmers* and *cstheory* ;(

Comment: The download link is not working

Comment: I get this msg "This add-on has been disabled by an administrator." Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have worked so far great (on FF4b2) its got the mentions for my SO and SA. However I can't add my stackoverflow username, I can add my SO and SA username but not SO. I type in Jonathan and it doesn't come up with my avatar. Could you make it possible to type in the number ID directly, without having to search for usernames. You'd only need to enable the textboxes.

Comment: Could you upload the extension so I can download it? The main link seems to be broken :/

Answer (score 3):

This is currently disabled on Firefox plug-in page:

[Mozilla.org > ADD-ONS >  Extensions > Swatch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/swatch/)

***Are there issues with this 'by-passing' controls, or allowing extra privileges?***

Comment: If you find it let me know where.