# API Help's CSS is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

The API Help page's CSS file, located at http://sstatic.net/so/all.css, is current returning 404 for me:

```
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>

  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
```

The documentation is still perfectly usable, just a little ugly. Not a deal breaker by any means, but just letting you know.

Comment: This will be fixed on the next deployment (probably tonight).

Answer (score 3):

They have moved also these favicons (hard-coded in [Swatch](https://stackapps.com/questions/316/swatch-a-firefox-plugin-for-monitoring-stack-exchange-sites-for-interesting-chan)):

http://sstatic.net/sf/favicon.ico
   http://sstatic.net/su/favicon.ico
   http://sstatic.net/sa/favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with sketchy site's css not working on iphones on cellular data, because that's just happened and it's a bit of a coincidence

Comment: Where did you hear that?

Comment: @George, here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64639/ also it happens to me.